# Manipulating a data.frame while keep the original content in Base R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I'm trying to `scale()` only numeric columns IF a `data.frame` contains a mix of numeric and non-numeric columns of data. (Initially, I am wondering if there could be an `if` statement showing if a `data.frame` contains non-numeric data?)

Note that I want to keep the original `data.frame` variables, and only add the new, `scale`d variables with the suffix `".s"` to the original `data.frame`.

I have tried **the following**. But it looks like it also populates the non-numeric column `Loc` in the below example?

```
stan <- function(data, scale = TRUE, center = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE){

 data <- if(na.rm) data[complete.cases(data), ]    

 ind <- sapply(data, is.numeric)
 data[paste0(names(data), ".s")] <- lapply(data[ind], scale)
 return(as.data.frame(data))
}
# EXAMPLE:
stan(iris)
```

Comment: I guess you want `data[paste0(names(data), ".s")] <- lapply(data[ind], scale)` instead of your two-line version

Comment: Oh right, you also need to subset the names, so `f = function(d) {ind <- sapply(d, is.numeric); d[paste0(names(d)[ind], ".s")] <- lapply(d[ind], scale); d}`

Comment: @Frank, that did it! Thank you! Frank, is there a logical test (`if()` statement) to check if a `data.frame` contains non-numeric data or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RE: your question on how to test whether your data frame has any non-numeric columns, you have a couple of ways to do this. Here's one:

```
all(sapply(iris, class) == "numeric")
# [1] FALSE
```

You can use that as your test in the `if` statement. It should be true exactly when `scale()` can produce a result.

Alternatively, you could `try` the offending `colMeans`, but that ends up being more complicated.

EDIT: since the OP accepted this as the answer, I'll add @Frank 's comment that answers the first part:

> `f = function(d) {ind <- sapply(d, is.numeric); d[paste0(names(d)[ind], ".s")] <- lapply(d[ind], scale); d}` - Frank

Comment: Your wrapping functions are treating the Species (setosa, versicolor, virginica) as numeric factors (1, 2, 3). We could treat those as factors, but would you say your result matches your expectations?

Comment: You state that you are testing if the dataframe has any non-numeric columns, and you get FALSE from your calculation meaning that there are no non-numeric columns which is not true. 

sapply(iris, class) == "numeric"  # gives an accurate result,
but I don't think wrapping it with all does.

Comment: @xy123  `all()` here indicates that there ARE non-numeric columns. In order to discover whether you can do `scale(DF)`,  you need a single logical value that says whether or not the all the columns are `"numeric"`.  `all(sapply(DF, class) == "numeric")` does exactly that. It returns `FALSE`, here, because there is one `FALSE` value in `sapply(iris, class) == "numeric"`. This means it will fail when `scale()` calls `colMeans(DF)`. Run it yourself (both versions). I think that will help clear it up.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`, you can do:

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
    mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(s = scale))
```

which will create the scaled columns with the suffix `_s` (no way to change this to `.s` as far as I know, although you can always do an additional renaming step).

Comment: Marius, I highly appreciate your valuable input. I'm more looking for a Base R solution.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution:

```
data <- data.frame(iris, scale(Filter(is.numeric, setNames(iris, paste0(names(iris), ".s")))))
```

Returns:

```
> head(data)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Length.s Sepal.Width.s Petal.Length.s Petal.Width.s
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa     -0.8976739    1.01560199      -1.335752     -1.311052
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa     -1.1392005   -0.13153881      -1.335752     -1.311052
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa     -1.3807271    0.32731751      -1.392399     -1.311052
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa     -1.5014904    0.09788935      -1.279104     -1.311052
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa     -1.0184372    1.24503015      -1.335752     -1.311052
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa     -0.5353840    1.93331463      -1.165809     -1.048667
```